# How can blood pressure be high but my pulse low?

Tags: blood, blood-pressure, cardiology, heart-rate

Someone whose blood pressure reads 188/134 with a pulse of 62. Read a few more times even after she woke up it stays in that area. Calm, not taking any drugs, normal weight, good health and not sick as far as she knows. What could cause this? Is it possible this can be her norm?

I was checking my vittles while sitting in a chair int he first paragraph as the diagram showed, but when I laid down they read 134/90 pulse 72 and stayed in that range. Second question would be can there be something that would effect the reading so differently just by sitting up?

Let me add a friend also used it and she was in the normal range while sitting.

Answer (score 5):

If that is the accurate pressure, you really need to go to the emergency room! 188 is high but not immediately dangerous, but 134 for a diastolic is outrageous.  At very least go to an urgent care or a pharmacy and have it double checked.

To answer the original question, blood pressure and pulse are not directly related.  The body regulates both separately to respond to environmental and internal conditions, but there is no direct 1:1 correlation. Pulse is how often the heart squeezes; pressure is how hard it squeezes, though technically that's the systolic pressure; and, in the case of diastolic (the lower number) pressure, it's how well or poorly the heart relaxes after squeezing).

A pressure of 188/134 would be severely hypertensive with likely diastolic heart failure;   A number like that, though, to me, screams poor equipment or poor technique, which is most likely the case if you are not being professionally tested and especially if you are improperly using a home testing system.

Comment: Yeah, I'm really skeptical of the 188/134 number. I agree that it sounds like faulty equipment or faulty operator.